# Concatenate email .HTMLBody to a group inbox reply

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have Excel VBA code that searches a group inbox subfolder for the first email with a matching subject. It then replies to all.

I cannot add my text to the rest of the email.

I've seen many responses to similar problems that show `.HTMLBody = "test" & .HTMLBody` but when the debug reaches this line, the second `.HTMLBody` is shown as

> application-defined or object-defined error

```vb
Sub Find_Email()

    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olReply As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim olNS As Namespace
    Dim olMailbox As Folder
    Dim olFolder As Folder
    Dim subFolder As Folder
    Dim BodyText As String

    Set olNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olMailbox = olNS.Folders("Group_Inbox")
    Set olFolder = olMailbox.Folders("test_Folder")
    Set subFolder = olFolder.Folders("test_subFolder")
    Set olItems = subFolder.Items

    TheDate = Format(Date, "DD-MM-YYYY")
    TheDate1 = Format(Date, "YYYY-MM")
    TheDate2 = Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD")
    TheDate3 = Format(Date, "YYYY")

'Find most recent email and populate

    olItems.Sort "ReceivedTime", True
    For i = 1 To olItems.Count
        Set olMail = olItems(i)
        If InStr(olMail.Subject, "Desired_Subject " & TheDate) > 0 Then
            Set olReply = olMail.ReplyAll
            With olReply
                .Display
                .To = "Recipients@gmail.com"
                .CC = ""
                .Subject = "Test_Subject"
                '.Attachments.Add "Document_destination"
                .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
                .HTMLBody = "This is a test email sending in Excel" & .HTMLBody ' This is the problem line.
                Exit Sub
            End With
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

I understand it might be the fact it is in a group inbox, which means that it could work for you.

Comment: `"This is a test email sending in Excel" & .HTMLBody ` does not return valid HTML?

Comment: I couldn't tell you im afraid. but I've tried .Body without the format line instead and the same issue

Comment: Unless there is a specific reason you could start in Outlook rather than Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (i can't test it, just a thought )

```
'Somewehere declare this string variable
Dim incomingHTMLBody as string

olItems.Sort "ReceivedTime", True
For i = 1 To olItems.Count
    Set olMail = olItems(i)
    If InStr(olMail.Subject, "Desired_Subject " & TheDate) > 0 Then
        incomingHTMLBody = olMail.HTMLBody
        Set olReply = olMail.ReplyAll
        With olReply
            .Display
            .To = "Recipients@gmail.com"
            .CC = ""
            .Subject = "Test_Subject"
            '.Attachments.Add "Document_destination"
            .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
            .HTMLBody = "This is a test email sending in Excel" & incomingHTMLBody
            Exit Sub
        End With
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I have actually tried something similar before, but in this (above) it now gives the same error -incomingHTMLBody = olMail.HTMLBody- in this line.

Comment: I'm not sure if the previous body is actually being stored. Is there a way to ensure that it is?

Comment: I assume you have tried: console.log(olMail.HTMLBody) and console.log(olMail.HTMLBody.length) and got the same error?

Comment: yes, same problem

Answer (score 0):

You may need a bit more care referencing Outlook objects in your environment.

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Sub Find_Email()

Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
Set objApp = CreateObject("outlook.application")

Dim objNS As Namespace
Set objNS = objApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Dim objMailbox As Outlook.Folder
Set objMailbox = objNS.Folders("Group_Inbox")

Dim objFolder As Outlook.Folder
Set objFolder = objMailbox.Folders("test_Folder")

Dim subFolder As Outlook.Folder
Set subFolder = objFolder.Folders("test_subFolder")

Dim objItems As Outlook.Items
Set objItems = subFolder.Items

Dim TheDate As Date
TheDate = Format(Date, "DD-MM-YYYY")

'Find most recent email and populate

objItems.Sort "ReceivedTime", True

Dim i As Long

Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem     ' olMail is not a good variable name
Dim objReply As Outlook.MailItem

Debug.Print objItems.Count

For i = 1 To objItems.Count

    Debug.Print objItems(i).Subject
    
    If objItems(i).Class = olMail Then   ' verify item is a mailitem
    
        Set objMail = objItems(i)
        
        If InStr(objMail.Subject, "Desired_Subject " & TheDate) > 0 Then

            Set objReply = objMail.ReplyAll
            With objReply
                .Display
                .To = "Recipients@gmail.com"
                .CC = ""
                .Subject = "Test_Subject"
                '.Attachments.Add "Document_destination"
                .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
                
                Debug.Print .htmlbody   ' verify property is available
                
                .htmlbody = "This is a test email sending in Excel" & .htmlbody ' This is the problem line.
                
                Exit For
            End With
        End If
        
    End If
    
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Really sorry, this doesn't seem to fix it either. Same issue in the same place. HTMLbody is undefined when its called.

Comment: Would you confirm you see output for `Debug.Print .htmlbody`.

Comment: the Debug.Print .htmlbody causes the same error

Comment: But if i dont add a body. the replyall has all the previous emails within it. Just if i add a body it is overwritten

Comment: If the `Debug.Print .htmlbody` causes the same error, this indicates the property is the problem not the concatenate. Try the code in Outlook if the property is not available in Excel in your environment.

Comment: Thsi 100% is the reason. Thank you so much